# How to prevent subprocess.Popen from taking focus

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm working on a program and I need to implement some code that opens a txt file on a new tab in VS Code if it's already opened.
My problem is that every time it opens a new tab, it takes the focus onto VS Code, which annoys me when I'm doing some other things on my PC.

At first, I just wanted to open the new tab, which was working perfectly:

```
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Users\\Captain_Dada\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe', '--new-window', '--reuse-window', str(os.fspath(txtfile))])
```

I then wanted to stop taking focus when I noticed it (**the following method doesn't work**):

```
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Users\\Captain_Dada\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe', '--new-window', '--reuse-window', str(os.fspath(txtfile))], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

So, is there even a way to prevent `subprocess.Popen` from taking focus when being called, and if so, could you please help me to get it?

Answer (score 0):

So, I made a fix that seems temporary but I think I'm just going to keep it because it works and it's simple:

I made a function that return the name of the current window's executable:

```py
def FocusedWindow() -> str:
    hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()                                                                                   # Fetches the current focused window's handle
    window_pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)[-1]                                                            # Gets the window's ProcessID (PID)
    process_handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | win32con.PROCESS_VM_READ, False, window_pid) # Opens a Process Handle with the PID
    process_name = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(process_handle, 0)                                                      # Gets the full path to the executable
    executable_name = process_name.split("\\")[-1]                                                                          # Retrieve the executable in the path
    return executable_name                                                                                                  # returns the executable name (for example 'Code.exe' for VS Code)
```

And here is the actual `subprocess.Popen` part:

```py
OFW = FocusedWindow()                                                                                       # OFW = Originally Focused Window
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Path\\To\\VS Code\\Code.exe', '--new-window', '--reuse-window', os.fspath(txtfile)]) # Opening the subprocess with Popen
if OFW != 'Code.exe':                                                                                       # Checks if the user was already on 'Code.exe' (VS Code's executable)
    while FocusedWindow() != 'Code.exe":                                                                    # If not, loops until the current Focused Window is VS Code
        pass
    pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')                                                                          # When the Focused Window is VS Code (or an executable named 'Code.exe'), Tabs out of the window
```

Here are the imported modules if you need them:

```
subprocess | win32process | win32gui | win32api | win32con | pyautogui
```

Please note that this may be confusing, because it changes the order of the windows in the Alt + Tab menu, but at least it works fine in most interpreters (if not all?)

You also can store the `subprocess.Popen` in a variable and do `variable.terminate()` (with "variable" being yours) when you're finished with the window, but it won't work everywhere (not in VS Code for example)